# Propiedad undefined en los métodos de la misma clase

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo en un componente: un Array de elementos iniciada vacía. En el constructor le añado elementos que me traigo de otra clase, de esta forma:

```
  elementos: Elemento[] = [];

  constructor(private _elementosService: ElementosService) {

    this.elementos = this._elementosService.getElementos();
  }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Ahora, en el método `ngOnInit()` simplemente para probar que la lista elementos ha sido cargada, realizo un `console.log(this.elementos);` y si compilo y veo la consola, en efecto, me devuelve los valores que estoy esperando.

**Problema**

Dentro de la misma clase tengo varios métodos y en uno de ellos necesito utilizar una propiedad de los elementos que guardo en el Array. Pero dentro del método me indica que los elementos es `undefined`. 
Esto es lo que hay en el metodo:

```
let contenedor = document.getElementById('interior') as HTMLInputElement;
let idElemento: string = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); 
let parrafos = document.querySelectorAll('p');

switch(idElemento){

  case "jumbotronJS": {
    contenedor.innerHTML += this.elementos[0].codigo; // Añadir Jumbotron
    break;
  }
  case "parrafoJS": {
    contenedor.innerHTML += this.elementos[1].codigo; // Añadir Parrafo
    break;
  }
  case "cardJS": {
    contenedor.innerHTML += this.elementos[2].codigo; // Añadir Card
    break;
  }
  case "imagenJS": {
    contenedor.innerHTML += this.elementos[3].codigo; // Añadir Imagen
    break;
  }
  case "botonJS": {
    contenedor.innerHTML += this.elementos[4].codigo; // Añadir Boton
    break;
  }
  case "formularioJS": {
    contenedor.innerHTML += this.elementos[5].codigo; // Añadir Formulario
    break;
  }
}
```

¿Por que en el `constructor`, y en el `ngOnInit` mi Array de elementos esta cargada, y cuando la utilizo en otros métodos me la trae como `undefined`?

Esto es lo que necesito cargar:

```
this.elementos[0].codigo;
```

Comment: Hola. Si trabajas directamente el html en angular como lo estas haciendo vas a tener muchos problemas. Angular no detectara los cambios. Ten cuidado. Te recomiendo usar [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Comment: Soy nuevo en Angular, y aun hay cosas que hago a la antigua. No conocía esto, me lo veré bien. Gracias!

Comment: donde esta definido el metodo que intenta acceder a `this.elementos`? como se invoca?. El hecho de que reporte `this.elementos` como `undefined` significa que el metodo fue invocado con *otro* `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado. No me estaba detectando la interfaz si la iniciaba en el `constructor` ni en el `ngOnInit`. Por lo tanto he tenido que instanciarlo dentro del método:

```
let _elementoService: ElementosService = new ElementosService();
let elementos = _elementoService.getElementos();
```

Y de esta forma me lo ha detectado al momento. Aunque solo sera detectable en este método.

Comment: si haces eso no funcionará la injeccion de dependencias en `ElementosService`. No te recomiendo eso

Answer (score 0):

debes tener en cuenta el orden de ejecución de tus funciones, el problema puede ser debido a que la función que te trae undefined se ejecute antes de que el array se llene sobre todo si usas  innerHTML, creo que puedes solucionar esto poniendo un timeOut a tu función dando tiempo a tu array a cargarse.

```
setTimeout(() => {
     miFuncion();
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: El método ngOnInit es el primer que carga la aplicación ante cualquier cosa. Incluso antes que el constructor, por ello no influye, en este caso, el orden de los métodos.

Comment: Falso. El método `ngOnInit` es un método de tu clase componente... Como cualquier otra clase, primero se ejecuta el constructor. Una vez está la instancia creada, *Angular* ejecuta el método `ngOnInit`. Deberías echar un vistazo a [la documentación](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). De todas formas, la respuesta de @WillyAndreu es arbitraria e incorrecta.

Comment: Cierto. Aun estoy asimilando cosas de Angular y confundo a veces. Gracias por la información.